# Strong stability preserving RK scheme

Tags: time-integration

For the ODE

$$
\dot{x} = f(x)
$$

we have the 2-stage, second order SSP RK scheme (Shu, Osher, Gottlieb)

$$
x^{(0)} = x^n
$$

$$
x^{(1)} = x^{(0)} + \Delta t f(x^{(0)})
$$

$$
x^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} x^n + \frac{1}{2}[ x^{(1)} + \Delta t f(x^{(1)})]
$$

$$
x^{n+1} = x^{(2)}
$$

What is the scheme in case of the following ODE

$$
\dot{x} = f(x,t)
$$

In particular I am looking for papers which deal with this case.

Comment: You've seen "Heun's method", by any chance?

Comment: Thanks. Heun's method is what I was looking for. Similarly, is there an extension of the 3-stage SSPRK scheme ?

Comment: The operator $f$ could also depend explicitly on $t$. See Equation (2.11) in Osher and Shu' paper "Efficient implementation of essentially non-oscillatory shock-capturing schemes".